# Keep getting else/elif invalid syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, syntax-error

Currently I'm writing a code where I want to ask motor values from motor controller using raspberry pi. However my code is throwing `InvalidSyntax Error` in else and elif statements. I've already read about if and elif statements in python, but I can't figure out mistake by myself. The code is below:

```
def motor_values():

  while 1:
      command_1 = '?A '+str(1)+' \r' #Asking first motor current
      command_2 = '?A '+str(2)+' \r' #Asking second motor current
      counter = 0
      #First motor current
      if counter = 0:
        ser.write(command_1.encode()) #string to bytes
        data_1 = ser.readline().decode().strip() #bytes to string
        #Checking if data is received and extracting current value
        if 'A=' in data_1:
            value_1 = int(data_1.split('=')[1])
            print("Motor Current(Channel 1): " + str((value_1) + " Ampers")
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("Message is not received")
      #Second motor current
      elif counter == 1:
        ser.write(command_2.encode()) #string to bytes
        data_2 = ser.readline().decode().strip() #bytes to string
        if 'A=' in data_2:
            value_2 = int(data_2.split('=')[1])
            print("Motor Current(Channel 2): " + str((value_2) + " Ampers")
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("Message is not received")
      else:
        counter = 0
```

Comment: what line exactly throws the error? also, check your indentation - there seem to be 1-2 spaces where there should be 4.

Comment: @MrFuppes First `else' statement throwing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few syntax errors here:

1. use `==` in the if clause condition

```py
      #First motor current
      if counter == 0:  #
```

2. remove one of the two `(` in `str((value_2)`

```py
print("Motor Current(Channel 1): " + str(value_1) + " Ampers")
print("Motor Current(Channel 2): " + str(value_2) + " Ampers")
```

Comment: I'd suggest to an f-string... `f"Motor Current(Channel 1): {value_1} Ampers"`

Comment: @MrFuppes agreed there are always better ways to improve the code, but first step is to point out where goes wrong, not sure which python3 version Alex is using though (i have something in mind that raspberry pi comes with python 3.5.x by default)

Comment: right, wasn't mean as a critique, but more of an 'outlook' where one could go with this. good point there with the python version.

Answer (score 0):

you missed closing brace in print function

```
print("Motor Current(Channel 1): " + str(value_1) + " Ampers")
```